# Unknown origin of code in rendered HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, css, master-pages

This is homework. I'm creating an ASP.NET site using Master Pages, in Visual Studio 2012, and my navigation menu is too far to the left.  This is part of the rendered HTML, but I don't know where it's coming from, because I did a search in the whole solution for keywords contained in it.  I closed my browser, reopened it, cleared my cache, but the nav menu is still too far to the left.  I was using some css I copied from somewhere, but I deleted most of it.

```
<a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink" style="position:absolute;left:-10000px;top:auto;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;">Skip Navigation Links</a><div class="menu" id="NavigationMenu">
```

Comment: are you asking WHY the nav is too far left? OR How to remove the inline styles from the HTML?

Comment: Why it's too far to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's these settings:  `position:absolute; left:-10000px;`

Comment: left:-10000px; knocked it off the page, so after entering different numbers, position:absolute; left:248px; worked.  I don't know why, but thank you.